# How to get list of available filters for a category using magento

Tags: magento

I am able to getting all the available filters for all products,

But i want only selected filters  for an category.(color,price..)

i tried in the following way, but it is giving blank response,

```
$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
        $category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(23);
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);

        $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
```